# My string reversing function appends “undefined” at the beginning

Tags: javascript, html

I have a short piece of HTML and JavaScript code. I wanted to write a function that reverses the input string. For example, input = `hello`, output = `olleh`.

This is what I have so far:

```js
function go() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML;
  var output = document.getElementById("input");
  var result = "";

  for (var i = input.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    result += input[i];
  }
  output.innerHTML = result;
}
onload = go;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="question4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="input">This text here</div>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Everything works fine, but the output has an `undefined` in front of the result. It looks like this:

> undefinedereh txet sihT

How do I make the `undefined` go away?

Comment: `var i = input.length-1;` - an array like `['a','b','c']` has length 3 but its last element is at position 2. Alternatively, just use `input.split("").reverse().join("");`

Comment: [Rubber Duck Debug](http://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code.

Comment: Damn, why is this question receiving so many downvotes? What's wrong with people at StackOverflow these days?

Comment: i didn't downvoted, but i assume that those question show about how much effort the OP put in the question, that really have nothing to do with html or javascript, its basic programming language, that's actually one of the first tasks you asked to do when you learn programming language, any language.

Comment: @jehna1 A simple off-by-one error like this is not an "interesting" question, and shows a lack of effort as Yan correctly assumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change: `var i = input.length` to `var i = input.length-1` because the first time you loop you will be attempting to get `input[i]` (where `i` is the length of the `input` array).

If the array has 10 items in it, `i` will be 10, however the correct index for element 10 is 9.

Comment: I know! I hate it when that happens!

Comment: i did ...  no explanation provided

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, cause array starts counting on 0, totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

start the loop from input.length-1